# Windows RT .NET compatibility

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, tablet, .net-framework-version

I just need to know if I need the same framework to develop an app for Windows 8 for Tablets (Windows RT) and PCs or the tablet one still uses .NET compact framework.

Comment: The same framework as what..? Are you talking about Windows RT? You need a Windows 8 machine to build for them, it's not a normal version of .NET.

Comment: it seems like i'm missing alot of info where do u think i can start my research?

Comment: i mean the same framework as eachothers if i develop an app for PC will it be the same if i develop it for tablet??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only type of applications that run on Windows RT (ie. the Tablet/ARM version of Windows 8) are Windows Store Apps. These are full-screen applications that run on top of the WinRT API.

You can use a subset of .NET 4.5 on these devices, and use XAML to build your interface just like you would with WPF on the desktop.

You can read more on MSDN - [.NET for Windows Store apps overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx). This article describes a lot of the changes between the main version of .NET and the Windows RT subset that's available to you. Generally, `Windows.Runtime` will provide alternatives to some of the .NET methods that no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/nick-landry/archive/2012/06/19/developing-apps-for-microsoft-surface-windows-8-windows-rt-and-windows-phone.aspx

here are all the info about that

Answer (score 0):

As for the .Net compatibility, the [.NET for Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx) link states that the a lighter version of the .Net Framework (aptly called ".NET for Windows Store apps") will be available in Windows RT and so the available APIs too will be a subset of those available in the Full Desktop Version of the Framework. Eg. In Windows RT, [Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will not be availble.

You can also create a **Portable Class Library** project to develop a .NET Framework library that can be used from a Windows Store app. The project must include .NET for Windows Store apps as one of the target platforms. This is useful when you want to build functionality that can be used from apps for different platforms, like Windows Phone app, desktop app, and Windows Store app.

[Dev Center - Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/apps/br211386.aspx) is the best (and official) place to get started.